# Run Alfresco SOLR in its own tomcat

Tags: tomcat, solr, alfresco

I tried to run SOLR in its own tomcat server but I cant get it working. The procedure to do so is not well documented (http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/solr-install-config.html) and I feel I am missing something. Also on the second step it says

> Copy the context.xml file to apache-tomcat-6.0.26\conf\Catalina\localhost\solr.xml

How can I copy a file into a file? I only can copy the content of it and I did so. In the solr.zip file there are so many files and folders but I dont know what to do with them. I finished every step the documentation told me to but I cant get the SOLR context to be initialised from tomcat:

> Feb 12, 2015 4:40:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
>
> CRITICAL: Exception starting filter SolrRequestFilter
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal

Can someone help me please? I am struggling for hours now!

Comment: Those instructions worked just fine for me when I needed to do it. As for the first question, it's very easy! You're copying a file to both a new folder *and* a new name in that folder

Comment: so in my tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost folder I should have 2 files "context.xml" and "solr.xml" with the same content?

Comment: Okay maybe my english is not that good bu the documentation is rly hard for me:) Can you tell me which files belong to where and what content they should have? In the solr.xml in tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost there is the <Context> which contains the docBase and the solr/home. Where does the solr.xml from the zip belongs to which contians <core> and <solr /> ??? Sorry to annoy me but tomcat and application deployment is completly new for me.

Comment: I meant "annoy *you*"

Comment: Assuming you're using Alfresco Enterprise, you'd be best off giving Alfresco support a call. They have people speaking a wide range of languages, hopefully including yours, and can talk you through the process in your own language explaining everything as they go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the issue because, tomcat instance has no **xalan.jar** file in class path.

And this should be the content of solr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Context docBase="D:/alfresco/alf_data/solr/apache-solr-1.4.1.war" debug="0" crossContext="true">
    <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="D:/alfresco/alf_data/solr" override="true"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The xalan.jar was missing!

Comment: YW, glad that helped.